# Count Distinct IDs against type and Date in SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2, aggregation

I have table where data looks like this. I am finding the total count of each `TYPE` against `DATE`.

[image: Table]

So for above data output would be:

[image: Output Required]

I tried following query but result contain duplicates counted more than once.

```
SELECT 
    DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Existing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "EXISTING",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "NEW"
FROM 
    mytab
WHERE 
    DATE >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY    
    DATE ;
```

Output of Above query:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps what you want:

```
SELECT 
    DATE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Existing' THEN ID END) AS "EXISTING",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TYPE = 'New' THEN ID END) AS "NEW"
FROM 
    mytab
WHERE 
    DATE >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY    
    DATE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to do conditional aggregation on top of a subquery which first takes only distinct records from your original table.

```sql
SELECT 
    DATE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Existing' THEN 1 END) AS "EXISTING",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'New' THEN 1 END) AS "NEW"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, TYPE, DATE FROM mytab) t
WHERE DATE >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY DATE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking of avoiding the subquery as data might grow to Mns. Can we use any analytical fns to achieve this horizontal aggregation with distinct counts?

Comment: I don't understand what else you want to do here.